# What are these two Lego parts?

Tags: part-identification

I want to order these 2 missing pieces but I don't know the name of them, can anybody help? What are the part numbers?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

These parts are:

[image]

- [Item No: 2412b : Tile, Modified 1 x 2 Grille with Bottom Groove / Lip](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2412b#T=C)

and

[image]

- [Item No: 6266 : Leg Skeleton](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6266#T=C)

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU !!!!!!!!! you made me very happy !

Comment: Hi Andy and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please take the [tour] and check the [help] to learn more about using this site. In particular, if an answer has helped you, you should mark it as accepted with the checkmark icon to indicate that your question has been properly answered.